# Media Player перестает работать после 30 нажатий на кнопки с вызовом media player

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Media Player перестает работать после 30 нажатий
там 42 аудио файла. но 1 оставил для примера кода.

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaPlayer skorhots1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_korolevahots);
    skorhots1= mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.korhots1);
}

public void playSound (View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bkorhots1: mediaPlayer (skorhots1); break;
    }
}

private void mediaPlayer (MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: попробуйте вызывать метод release при старте если нужно

Comment: MediaPlayer имеет ограничения на количество загруженных (готовых к воспроизведению) экземпляров - сколько именно неизвестно и может различаться на разных версиях ОС и брендах. Нужно как-то предусмотреть выгрузку лишних. Или может воспроизводить треки другим способом. Опишите смысл и схему работы приложения подробнее - возможно вам подскажут решение.

Comment: soundboard по игре в жанре RTS. жмешь кнопку - воспроизводится фраза персонажа. soundpool решает проблему, но приносит другие. например, обрезка по длительности и невозможность регулировки громкости

Comment: Код неправильный у media player. В интернете есть решения

Comment: а что именно неправильно? уже нет идей. все перепробовал